# Passing arguments from asm to C in on ARM

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I read a lot of topics on this forum and found a lot of answers on this subject. I achieved to pass 5 arguments to a C function from my assembly code. For doing this, i used the instructions below :

```
mov r0, #0
mov r1, #1
mov r2, #2
mov r3, #3
mov r4, #4
STR r4, [sp, #-4]!
BL displayRegistersValue
```

But today i'm trying to pass the whole registers to a C function to save them in a C structure. I tried with this instruction :

```
STMDB sp!, {registers that i want to save}
```

My C function :

```
displayRegistersValue(int registers[number_of_registers])
char printable = registers[0] + (int)'0'; // Convert in a printable character
print_uart0(&printable);
```

But my display is not good. So, how I can access to the registers in C code?

Comment: Before/after `STMDB`, you need `mov r0, sp`.  This will pass a pointer to your 'C' routine as the first parameter.  Then your code should work.

Comment: I wouldn't count on it.  You never know what the compiler wants to save to the stack.  this, other junk, etc.  Safer to just give it the address itself.  Still, I don't think OP understands pointers, which is getting in the way.

Comment: The compiler will reserve the space it needs on the stack; it shouldn't overwrite previous stack frames.  The `sp!` means to update the stack pointer after the save.  He seems to be using the correct stack direction for EABI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure the ARM standard only allows R0-R3 to be passed by value so 4 max.  If you need more values, then push them onto the stack and access them that way - like the compiler does.  Or make a struct and pass its address.

Ok, doubled cheked and I was right [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) is a link to the ARM calling conventions - down the page a bit.

To do what you want, pass the address of some memory location (an array) into your assembly routine.  Once you have that address, probably within r0, you can stmdb! into that location all your register values and that memory will be viewable at the C level.

Beware, this probably isn't going to do what you think it will.  Those values are allowed to change quite a bit as per the calling convention link above.  If this is for debugging, you are better off using a debugger and watching the registers that way.

Ok, you are still not understanding here:

```
{
    int registerValues[14];

    myAsmRoutine(registerValues);

    print_uart0(& registerValues);
}

myAsmRoutine:
    stmia  r0!, {r1-r14}
    blx   lr
```

I skipped R0 and PC, but you get the idea.  Also, you will need to do something a bit mroe complex to change the values into a printable format - sprintf or itoa os something like that.

Comment: Ok so I have to set the number of my function's argument to the number of registers that I want to save ?

Comment: No.  1 argument is passed - an address to memory.  That address is stored in the register and used to save your values.

Answer (score 2):

```
displayRegistersValue(int registers[number_of_registers])
```

this is an array not a structure and is passed as a pointer to something not as a long list of items.  same goes for structures btw.

It is usually easiest to construct a C function that does what you want in asm then see what the compiler produces, then go from there (use the ABI document to confirm, etc).

```
#define NUMREGS 13
void displayRegistersValue(unsigned int registers[NUMREGS]);
void outer ( void )
{
    unsigned int regs[NUMREGS];
    displayRegistersValue(regs);
}

> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O2 -c fun.c -o fun.o
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objdump -D fun.o

fun.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <outer>:
   0:   e52de004    push    {lr}        ; (str lr, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e24dd03c    sub sp, sp, #60 ; 0x3c
   8:   e28d0004    add r0, sp, #4
   c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <displayRegistersValue>
  10:   e28dd03c    add sp, sp, #60 ; 0x3c
  14:   e49df004    pop {pc}        ; (ldr pc, [sp], #4)
```

You will need to do something similar, make room on the stack by adding to the stack pointer, save the lr so you dont trash it with the branch link, copy your registers to that memory (the stack) point r0 to the beginning of the memory/array you want to pass, then call the function (r0 being the first and only parameter you are passing to the function).

```
push {lr} 
mov lr,sp 
stmdb sp!,{r0-r12} 
mov r0,lr 
bl displayRegistersValue
add sp,sp,#52
pop {lr}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `objdump`.  `objdump` is an excellent tools for people who understand assembler to diagnose many issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I'll try all your solutions this night.

Answer (score 0):

An array is passed as a pointer in a single register. If you want 5 registers then you need to have 5 parameters (int i1, int i2 etc.).

Comment: Ok, so if I understood, I need 13 parameters in my C function if I want to pass 13 registers ? Is there another way ? You said that an array is passed as a pointer so in a single register. So it assumes that the pointer is stored in r0. But what is stored ? address or value of the pointer ?

Answer (score 0):

To quote from the ARM APCS document:

"The first four registers r0-r3 (a1-a4) are used to pass argument values into a subroutine and to return a result value from a function. They may also be used to hold intermediate values within a routine (but, in general, only between subroutine calls)."

So if you want to pass more than 4 values to a C function, you need to pass the rest of the values on the stack. A better idea would be to put the register values in a memory region that has been statically allocated and pass the address of the memory (pointer) to the C function. The pointer can be de-referenced by the function to get to the register values.